# Holomorphs and split extensions

Tags: group-theory, definition, group-cohomology, semidirect-product

The notion "holomorph" was introduced in Maria S. Voloshina's Ph.D. thesis *On the Holomorph of a Discrete Group* (available at https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0302120). It is defined as follows:

Let $G$ be a group and let $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ be the automorphism group of $G$. The holomorph of $\mathrm{Hol}(G)$, is defined as follows:

1. As a set, $\mathrm{Hol}(G)=\mathrm{Aut}(G)\times G$;
2. For each $x,y\in G$ and $f,g\in\mathrm{Aut}(G)$, the multiplication on $\mathrm{Hol}(G)$ is defined by $$(f,x)\cdot(g,y)=(fg, g^{-1}(x)y)\text{.}$$

The author points out that there is a split exact sequence $$1\to G\to\mathrm{Hol}(G)\stackrel{\leftarrow}{\rightarrow}\mathrm{Aut}(G)\to1\text{.}$$

What I am confused about is, if there is such a split exact sequence, doesn't the [splitting lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma) imply that $\mathrm{Hol}(G)$ is isomorphic to $G\times\mathrm{Aut}(G)$?

Comment: Fix your sequence. There is no $K$.

Comment: @KCd, thanks! It was fixed.

Comment: Your groups are not generally abelian, so that "splitting lemma" does not apply. The splitting you describe corresponds to an isomorphism with a *semidirect* product, and indeed the group structure you describe on the holomorph makes it a semidirect product of $G$ and ${\rm Aut}(G)$. See Theorems 3.2 and 3.3 of http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/splittinggp.pdf.

Comment: Thanks @KCd! I forgot the condition on the splitting lemma and now it is very clear to me. Am wondering if you happen to know anything about my latest question at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/193755/very-frustrated-reading-a-proof-of-the-faithfulness-of-artins-representation-of

Comment: While Voloshina's thesis (2003) is about holomorphs, that concept was *not* introduced there for the first time. I can find it, with that name, in Birkhoff and Mac Lane's *Algebra* from the 1960s and the Wikipedia page on holomorphs lists Marshall Hall's group theory book from 1959 at the end.

Comment: Thanks for introducing the history of holomorph, @KCd!!

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer to the question that seems to have already been resolved in the comments.

---

As Prof. Conrad noted, the holomorph $\text{Hol}(G)$ of a group $G$ is isomorphic to the semidirect product $G\rtimes_\sigma \text{Aut}_{\text{Grp}}(G)$, where $\text{Aut}_{\text{Grp}}(G)$ is the group of group automorphisms of $G$, and $\sigma=\text{id}_{\text{Aut}_{\text{Grp}}(G)}:\text{Aut}_{\text{Grp}}(G)\to \text{Aut}_{\text{Grp}}(G)$ is the standard action.

An example of this group (interpreted at least measurably, so that the automorphisms are required to be at least Borel measurable; see e.g. [Measurable group homomorphisms are continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3996050/169085)) when $G$ is commutative is the so-called affine group; one can similarly consider affine transformations of tori; see [Example of a continuous affine group action](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3304441/169085), [Question about Stillwell Naive Lie theory exercise 4.6.3](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4612602/169085), [Dynamics on the torus](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4452120/169085). The second discussion is especially relevant. Indeed, note that $\text{Hol}(\mathbb{R})$ is isomorphic to

$$\mathbb{R}\rtimes \text{GL}(1,\mathbb{R})\cong (\mathbb{R},+)\rtimes (\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\},\cdot), $$

so that both groups involved are abelian, and there is a short exact sequence

$$0\to\mathbb{R}\to \text{Hol}(\mathbb{R})\to \text{GL}(1,\mathbb{R})\to 1,$$

however this sequence is not in the category of abelian groups (it's in the category of possibly nonabelian groups).

---

Finally as a historical comment, the notion of the "holomorph of a group" goes at least to Burnside's 1897 book *Theory of Groups of Finite Order* (available at https://archive.org/details/cu31924086163726).